# Does Frida have functionality to support tracing memory modifications?

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, frida

I’m using the javascript bindings of frida on iOS and I want to trace all memory modifications made by a thread. I don’t mean at a specific location like memory access monitor usually is used for. I have a thread that uses dispach_once and pthread_once and I want all modifications from those to be traced too. What I mean by modifications is any write to the memory in the heap or code pages, and not reading code pages, writing regs, or any of that. Just explicit changes to memory that I assume is a static C variable or structure. Any help is very much appreciated thanks. Side note: the application has defense measures against lldb and some defenses for frida-stalker also :( so idk what will work... I also don’t mind switching to C instead of js but I need to to work on iOS a12+

Comment: Frida makes use of the debugger provided by iOS. I don't think that debuggers provide such a functionality,

Answer (score 0):

You can play with memory permissions and build something for your needs

Intercept & log who read/write to x2 via removing permissions w/ mprotect.

```js
Process.setExceptionHandler(exp => {
  console.warn(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(exp, { _lr: DebugSymbol.fromAddress(exp.context.lr), _pc: DebugSymbol.fromAddress(exp.context.pc) }), null, 2));
  Memory.protect(exp.memory.address, Process.pointerSize, 'rw-');
  return true; // goto PC 
});

Interceptor.attach(funcPtr, {
  onEnter(args) {
    console.log('onEnter', JSON.stringify({
      x2: this.context.x2,
      mprotect_ret: Memory.protect(this.context.x2, 2, '---'),
      errno: this.errno
    }, null, 2));
  }
});
```